# c# get the next string in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array which contains strings. I want to compare my current string with all of the strings inside the array and get the next alphabetical one out.
How do I do this?

**Clarification**: The strings arent in any order. I want to know which index has the next string which has the next alphabetical order. For example if I have the String "Bananas" the next String I want from "Apple" "Oranges" "Bananas" would be "Oranges".

given the array

```
var fruit = new[] { "Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas" }
```

I want a function that would pass this test

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, NextGreatestIndex(fruit, 2))
```

because `"Oranges"` is alphbetically next after `"Bananas"`.

Comment: use a string comparer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: define next. Do you mean, that if all the string were ordered in alphabetical order, you want the first string after your current string?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify or it is likely to get closed.

Comment: The strings arent in any order. I want to know which index has the next string which has the next alphabetical order. For example if I have the String "Bananas" the next String I want from "Apple" "Oranges" "Bananas" would be "Oranges"

Comment: @zanzoken There seems to have been a little confusion about exactly what you mean and that comment should really be edited into the question. Can you please do that.

Comment: I've made my answer work, and to your specification.

Comment: add some example code that you tried, so that we understand what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The strings arent in any order. I want to know which index has the
>   next string which has the next alphabetical order. For example if I
>   have the String "Bananas" the next String I want from "Apple"
>   "Oranges" "Bananas" would be "Oranges"

With LINQ it's easy:

```
string[] fruits = {"Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas"};
string fruit = "Bananas";
string next = fruits.OrderBy(s => s).FirstOrDefault(f => string.Compare(f, fruit) > 0);
```

If there's no fruit behind `next` will be `null`.

Maybe you want to persist a sorted collection for future lookups to avoid reordering all the time.

You could use a `SortedSet<string>` and it's [`GetViewBetween`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381801(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var sortedFruits = new SortedSet<string>(fruits);
next = sortedFruits.GetViewBetween(fruit, sortedFruits.Max).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that the set keeps it's ordering even if you add new items. It also skips duplicates, but that should not be a problem in this case since you just want to get the next item alphabetically.

Comment: @zanzoken, curious that the accepted answer does not give an index as asked for in the question.

Comment: @Jodrell: this question was pretty unclear from the start. But OP wanted not the index but the next string in alphabetical order. _"For example if I have the String "Bananas" the next String I want from "Apple" "Oranges" "Bananas" would be "Oranges"."_ The index confused me also first.

Comment: I'm still confused, the question says "which index has the next string which has the next alphabetical order" but, you must be right, your answer is accepted.

Comment: @Jodrell: if he knows the index he knows the fruit, and that's all ;)

Answer (score 5):

1. Sort the array into your desired alphabetical order.
2. Find the index of the current string in that sorted array.
3. Return the string with next index.
4. Deal with the edge cases that the current string is not in the array or the current string is the final element of the array.

Comment: ...and for extra points, try making point 2. run in O(log N).

Comment: Look at String.Compare(). Once you sort your array as David mentioned you can loop through and compare your input with the next item in the array until the current value is > your input, then return it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can do is:

```
var strings = new[]{"apples","oranges","bananas"};

var sample = "apples";

var next = strings.OrderBy(i=>i).SkipWhile(i=>!i.Equals(sample)).Skip(1).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

And the most performant way is using BinarySearch, this way the operation would be O(log(N)) (you need to store the sorted list for repeated usage).

```
var sorted = strings.OrderBy(i=>i).ToList();

var sample = "bananas";

var index = sorted.BinarySearch(sample);

var next = index < 0 ? null : index >= sorted.Count - 1 ? null : sorted[index + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** now reflects clarified question.

Generic implementation that works with any `IList<T>` including an array of strings.

```
int NextGreaterIndex<T>(
        IList<T> list,
        int currentIndex,
        Comparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    }

    var result = -1;
    var best = default(T);
    var found = false;
    var current = list[currentIndex];

    for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == currentIndex)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var t = list[i];
        if (comparer.Compare(current, t) >= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (found && comparer.Compare(t, best) >= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        best = t;
        result = i;
        found = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

usage:

```
var fruit = new[] { "Apple", "Oranges", "Bananas" }
var answer = NextGreaterIndex(fruit, 2);
// answer == 1
```